# Date in PHP and Javascript are not match

Tags: javascript, php

As title, although I set with only value.
In Javascript:

```
var n = (new Date("2015 Oct 17")).getTime()/1000;
console.log(n);
// result: 1445014800
```

And PHP:

```
$unix = date('d-m-Y', 1445014800);
echo $unix;
// result: 16-10-2015
```

Please leave some explanations.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not parse strings using the Date constructor, it's implementation dependant. Manually parse the string using your own function (3 lines of code here) or a library (you'll spend more time learning the library than writing the function unless you have many other uses for it).

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript:

```
var n = (new Date("2015 Oct 17")).getTime()/1000;
console.log(n);
// result: 1445014800
```

The operation `/1000` is coercing your value to a numeric type, so the answer is correct!

Comment: What different between 1445014800000 (in ms) and 1445014800 (s)?

Comment: The time value returned by `new Date("2015 Oct 17"))` is entirely implementation dependent (it can be *NaN*), and also changes depending on the system time zone setting. The only way it will agree with a server time value is if both are set to the same timezone and both happen to parse the string to the same date and time (which would be by chance only).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, parsing of a string like "2015 Oct 17" is entirely implementation dependant. If it works at all, it is likely to be converted to a Date object representing the date at 00:00:00 at the start of the day in the time zone of the host system.

For a system whose time zone offset is, say, UTC+1000, and that parses the string as a local time, the time value in seconds will be 1445004000.

However, such a system might decide that the string is a bit like an ISO 8601 string, and it might decide that since such strings without a time zone were treated as UTC in ES5, that it will treat it as a UTC time. In that case, the time value in seconds will be 1445040000 (i.e. equivalent to 2015-10-17T00:00:00Z).

To reliably transfer dates between systems, it is often considered best to transfer time values in either seconds or milliseconds since the UNIX (and ECMAScript) epoch of 1070-01-01T00:00:00Z.

To create such a time value for 2015-Oct-17 you can use:

```
var timeValue = Date.UTC(2015, 9, 17);
```

To convert the UNIX time value 1445014800 to an ECMAScript date, you can do (noting that UNIX time values are in seconds and ECMAScript in milliseconds):

```
console.log(new Date(1445014800*1000).toISOString());  // 2015-10-16T17:00:00.000Z
```

So I'll assume that the PHP host is in a timezone that is UTC-05:00 and that 2015-Oct-17 has been treated as UTC.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked it, and this JS function returns

```
1445036400
```

which in 'human time' is

```
Fri, 16 Oct 2015 23:00:00 GMT
```

https://jsbin.com/wuvawupede/edit?js,console,output

http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: What `new Date("2015 Oct 17"))` returns is entirely implementation dependent, and also changes depending on the system time zone setting.